# wsadmin printing results with a single character per line

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I'm trying to use the output from some wsadmin commands to use in other commands, however, when I loop through the output, it seems to print a single character per line, which blows up my other commands. What do I need to add to make this not print a single character per line.

```
cell_name = AdminControl.getCell()
# Get the DMGR Complete Object Name
dmgr_object_name =  AdminControl.completeObjectName('WebSphere:name=DeploymentManager,type=DeploymentManager,mbeanIdentifier=DeploymentManager,*')
# Get the full Application Manager string. 
appManager = AdminControl.queryNames('cell=' + cell_name + ',type=ApplicationManager,*')

for jvm in appManager :
  print( jvm )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is to import the Java lineseparator

```
# get line separator
import  java.lang.System  as sys
lineSeparator = sys.getProperty('line.separator')
# Get the Cell Name
cell_name = AdminControl.getCell()
# Get the DMGR Complete Object Name
dmgr_object_name =  AdminControl.completeObjectName('WebSphere:name=DeploymentManager,type=DeploymentManager,mbeanIdentifier=DeploymentManager,*')
# Get the full Application Manager string. 
appManager = AdminControl.queryNames('cell=' + cell_name + ',type=ApplicationManager,*').split(lineSeparator)
```

This then allows the results to be split properly.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer complementary to @Pred's approach, with some additional explanation.

To clarify, the query `AdminControl.queryNames('cell=RandomCell1,type=ApplicationManager,*')` returns a `string` object, which looks like this:

`'WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=Node1,version=8.5.5.5,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=RandomCell1,spec=1.0\nWebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=dmgr,platform=proxy,node=Dmgr,version=8.5.5.5,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=RandomCell1,spec=1.0'`

So, iterating through the above string using a `for` loop prints each character in turn.

In the above string, each entry is separated by the `\n` (newline) character. So, split the string by the `\n` character.

`AdminControl.queryNames('cell=RandomCell1,type=ApplicationManager,*').split('\n')`

This returns a list of strings, each of which is one entry corresponding to one object. The list then looks like the one below:

`['WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=Node1,version=8.5.5.5,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=RandomCell1,spec=1.0', 'WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=dmgr,platform=proxy,node=Dmgr,version=8.5.5.5,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=RandomCell1,spec=1.0']`

Iterating through the list returns each entry as one full string.